# Fixing mime type on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus, mime-types

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. Sometime back after an update, all files in Ubuntu started showing a mime type of text/plain. This means that double clicking on any file opened it using gvim which is really annoying. How do I get Nautilus to recognize mime types based on file extension?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some poking around I found the answer and everything is back to normal. All I had to do was

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```